# How to display a new page using PageView.builder for a new date

Tags: flutter

I am a bit new to `PageView.builder`. I want to create a new page for a specific day (example : Jan 1, 2019 => page 1, jan 2, 2019 => page 2, and so on). When the user scrolls to the right, the a new page displaying the next day will be displayed and scrolling to the left will display the previous date. Is there anyway i can set this using `DateTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference this package https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_views 
 
github: https://github.com/ZedTheLed/calendar_views

the code you want to reference is here 
https://github.com/ZedTheLed/calendar_views/blob/master/lib/src/calendar_page_view/calendar_page_view.dart

code snippet of calendar_page_view.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new PageView.builder(
      scrollDirection: widget.scrollDirection,
      pageSnapping: widget.pageSnapping,
      reverse: widget.reverse,
      physics: widget.physics,
      onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
      controller: pageController,
      itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
    );
  }
```

[image]